# css files not loading with application.scss

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-sass

I added some css files to my vendor library and I am trying to get them to work on my app. I see the full css when I pull up my development page to look at the file

```
 http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/application.css.scss
```

but its not working on the actual page. When I look at the source code of the page I see

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
```

But it shows the js files but not the additional css files. Why would it show the js files but not the css files. I imported the additional css files to the application.scss like so...

```
@import "fontello";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "animation";
@import "hover";
@import "morphext";
@import "settings-ie8";
@import "settings";
@import "fontello-codes";
@import "fontello-embedded";
@import "fontello-ie7-codes";
@import "fontello-ie7";
@import "owl.carousel";
@import "owl.theme";
@import "owl.transitions";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-theme";
```

Like I said I see it in the application.scss file when I pull it up in the browser but its not working on the page. Here is the link on my page view...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: 'all', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "rails.validations", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I noticed that on the source code it shows turbolinks first and NOT the link href... to the application.css file. What am I missing?

--UPDATE--

I noticed however if i change the call of the css to manually add each css then it comes up in the source code,

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", "hover", media: 'all', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Source code of page becomes...

```
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/hover.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>  
etc...
```

so why is it not putting the css files together when i just call application.scss?

Comment: have you checked by restarting your `server` ? . It's good to restart and then test the css editing done in the file.

Comment: Yes, I did thats not it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you loaded vendor library in application.rb file like this:-

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets')
```

and then require these in your application.css.scss like:

```
@import "external_library/contents";
```

Comment: Also, the asset pipeline is on and it is recognizing the css files and finding them, for some reason it is just not applying it.